# Unfolding an integer

Tags: code-golf, sequence, restricted-complexity

Given the functions

```
L: (x, y) => (2x - y, y)
R: (x, y) => (x, 2y - x)
```

and a number `N` generate a minimal sequence of function applications which take the initial pair `(0, 1)` to a pair which contains `N` (i.e. either `(x, N)` or `(N, y)`).

Example: `N = 21`. The minimal sequence is of length 5, and one such sequence is

```
          (  0,  1)
1. L ---> ( -1,  1)
2. L ---> ( -3,  1)
3. R ---> ( -3,  5)
4. L ---> (-11,  5)
5. R ---> (-11, 21)
```

Write the shortest function or program you can which generates a minimal sequence in `O(lg N)` time and `O(1)` space. You may output / return a string in either application order (`LLRLR`) or composition order (`RLRLL`), but document which.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby, 55 or 39 characters

```
f=->n{(n>0?n-1:-n).to_s(2).tr'01',n>1?'LR':n<0?'RL':''}
```

The function returns the function sequence in composition order.

Usage:

```
puts f[21]     # RLRLL
puts f[-6]     # LLR
```

*Edit:* If we allow recursion (which violates the O(1) memory constraint but such does any function since the return value itself is O(lg n)) we can shrink the code to 39 characters.

```
f=->n{n<n*n ?f[(n-1)/2+1]+'RL'[n%2]:''}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <strike>82</strike> 81 Characters (complete program)

```
$n=<>;@_=(R,L);if($n<0){$n=1-$n;$a--}while($n>1){print$_[$n%2+$a];$n+=$n%2;$n/=2}
```

It takes one number as input, and it outputs the sequence in application order.

Edit: Instead of redefining the array in the if statement, set a number to negative one and add it to the index when the array is referenced. It achieves the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
“”HĊß;ị⁾LR$ƲḂƑ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4oCc4oCdSMSKw5874buL4oG@TFIkxrLhuILGkT//w4figqxZ//8yMSwgLTY)

This uses the same allowance in [Howard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3977/66833), in that we can use recursion, despite it violating the \$O(1)\$ memory requirement. If this isn't allowed, then the following 20 byte solution works instead:

```
ḶȯAṀ©Bị⁾LRUAƑ}¡$®aḟ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//4bi2yK9B4bmAwqlC4buL4oG@TFJVQcaRfcKhJMKuYeG4nzD/w4figqxZ//8yMSwgLTYsIDEsIDA)

Both output the composition order

### How they work

```
“”HĊß;ị⁾LR$ƲḂƑ? - Main link f(N). Takes N on the left
              ? - If statement:
             Ƒ  -   If: Invariant under:
            Ḃ   -     Bit; Yields 1 for 0/1, else 0
“”              -   Then: Return the empty string
           Ʋ    -   Else:
  H             -     N÷2
   Ċ            -     Ceiling
    ß           -     f(⌈N÷2⌉)
          $     -     Group the previous 2 links together as a monad g(N):
       ⁾LR      -       "LR"
      ị         -       Modular index N into "LR"
     ;          -     Append to f(⌈N÷2⌉)
```

The 20 byte version (+6 bytes to handle \$N = 0, 1\$):

```
ḶȯAṀ©Bị⁾LRUAƑ}¡$®aḟ0 - Main link. Takes N on the left
Ḷ                    - [0, 1, ..., N-1] for N > 0 else []
  A                  - abs(N)
 ȯ                   - Replace [] with abs(N)
   Ṁ                 - Max; N-1 if N > 0 else abs(N)
    ©                - Save this to the register R
     B               - Convert R to binary
               $     - Group the previous 2 links into a monad f(N):
       ⁾LR           -   "LR"
             }       -   To N:
            Ƒ        -     Invariant under:
           A         -       Absolute value; 1 if N ≥ 0 else 0
              ¡      -   Do the following that many times:
          U          -     Reverse "LR"
                         This yields "RL" if N ≥ 0 else "LR" 
      ị              - For each bit in R, index into "RL" or "LR",
                       yielding a list of Rs and Ls, S
                ®    - Yield R
                 a   - Replace all but R = 0 with S
                  ḟ0 - Change R = 0 to []
```